# Add no-width optional break character in RDLC word report

Tags: reporting-services, ms-word, rdlc

I am currently working on RDLC report to render MS Word Output using VS 2010. The output is used to print sticker labels (i.e. inside box). Hence it is very important for render texts exactly inside the table.
In some cases the a word becomes quite large that it expands the table and the table width is enlarged.
I am planning to insert "no-width optional break character" (refer http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/msoffice/use-words-no-width-optional-break-character-to-facilitate-wrapping/5385) for every alternative character in the word so that the word breaks and wraps to next line and the width of the table is not disturbed.

How to insert the "no-width optional break character" in RDLC report text box ?

Comment: can you show us your current codes ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iterate the text and insert "char zwob = '\u200C' " between each text. 
This unicode will insert "no-width optional break character" in RDLC/Word report.

Hence the text break whenever needed without expanding the table.